# Using method from one class into class

Tags: java, android

I have two classes:

- MyActivity.Java
- DatabaseHandler.Java

I would like to take the returning String from the method "getCurrentCar" and put it inside MyActivity.java

***DatabaseHandler.Java:***

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public Car getCurrentCar() {

            SQLiteDatabase db       =   getWritableDatabase();
            String sql              =   "SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
            Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
            Car car = null;

            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    car = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
                }
            }
            finally {
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                    db.close();
            }
            return car;
        }
}
```

I have attempted already, but the parameters are asking for Context.

```
//DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(contexthere);
DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler();
handler.getCurrentCar();
```

I would like to know how to take that return and put it inside my MyActivity.java so I can then use a BitmapFactory to recreate the image.

Thanks

Comment: Giving  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html, you cannot instantiate DatabaseHandler (a subclass) without a context, so you cannot call getCurrentCar

Comment: Hi robermann, thanks for the quick response. What exactly is the context of my method "DatabaseHandler"? As in, what defines what a context is.

Comment: Should contain runtime data, read on  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html.

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context` means current runtime :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...........
        ...........

         // you should  instantiate 'DatabaseHandler'  here
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); // "this" refer to the context

        ..........
        ..........

 // insert the rows
 db.createCar(new Car("Sesame street A","23423","anImage1"));
 db.createCar(new Car("Sesame street B","43543","anImage2"));

 // get the rows which you mean string
 for(Car cars : db.getCurrentCar()){
 String rows= "id : "+ cars.getID()+ " address : "+getAddress() + "postcode : "+getPostcode()+" image : "+getImage());
 }  
}
```

Just adapt `.getID(),getAddress(),getPostcode(),getImage()` based on the 'getter' methods name in your `Car` class, as I might write them wrongly

****** Codes above I write based on the file that you shared by a link. (your file missing `Car` class), but I just predict that it should be like above :

Comment: Hi Fev, I've applied this inside my main method on MyActivity.Java. It still appears to not be working. It says "cannot resolve symbol handler;"

Comment: which String do you mean ?? getCurrentCar() returns Car type not String type !!

Comment: I fear I have done this all wrong then... Basically it's meant to take a random value from the SQLite database and then return it as a string so I can use a BitmapFactory to draw it in an imageView.

Here are my two main classes: http://pastebin.com/EeYN75u4

Comment: maybe you mean String on this method   "public String getRandomImageKey() {}" as it returns a random string , i mean you call this method !

Comment: Hi Fev, thanks for being patient with me. That makes sense now. I've added it here: http://pastie.org/9413337

Does this mean I can use db.getRandomImageKey(); and it will return the value from the SQLite database?

Comment: db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM" + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null); on getRandomImageKey() methods means that it will return String containing row from column  KEY_ID which is "id" and KEY_IMAGE which is "image" , that's it !

Comment: just as I hoped! Thanks very very much! One last thing! I'm calling db.getRandomImageKey(); do I need to create something to allow me to put it inside this: http://pastebin.com/nDtPspbx 

As you can see I tried to make a new String using db.getRandomImageKey();

Comment: @Bradly , I'm sorry , forget about db.getRandomImageKey(), actually you could also get the rows by calling db.getCurrentCar() but it should be iterated first , *I've just modified my answer above .

Comment: Thank you very very much :) I have edited the for statement. However I have come up with a rather peculiar error http://puu.sh/ansI9/c738ff23f7.png

Comment: @BradlySpicer You should start a new question. Please be sure to include enough code that we can understand what you are asking. Also copy and paste the **exact** error message from the Problems view in Eclipse.